# Ruby, Qt and third party widgets

Tags: ruby, qt, qt4, kde4, qtruby

I'm learning Ruby and, for this, I'm writing an application in it. My background is in C++/Qt. So I've started writing a Ruby/Qt app.

But there's a few previously written widgets (C++) I would like to use, besides qwt.

Is this possible? If it is, how should I do it?

**PS**: It seems QtRuby from Korundum bindings do includes Qwt bindings. I've downloaded the bindings source from RubyForge and I'm trying to build it. CMake runs but even if I include the Qwt location in the command line, it skips building it.

```
vitorpy@myhost:~/qtruby/qt4-qtruby-2.1.0> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/kde4 -DENABLE_SMOKE=on -DENABLE_QTRUBY=on -DENABLE_QWT_SMOKE=on -DENABLE_QWT_RUBY=on -DQwt5_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/qwt-5.2.1/include -DQwt5_Qt4_LIBRARY=/usr/local/qwt-5.2.1/lib/libqwt.so
```

And it generates:

```
-- Build Ruby bindings: QtRuby;QtScript;QtTest;QtUiTools;QtWebKit
-- Skip Ruby bindings: Akonadi;KHTML;KIO;KTextEditor;Korundum;KrossRuby;Nepomuk;Okular;Phonon;Plasma;QScintilla;Qwt;Solid;Soprano
```

**Other resources**:
[Link](https://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=48881&forum_id=723) for my post on the RubyForge forum.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Ubuntu?

If it is the case, why giving you the trouble to build QtRuby and Qwt's Ruby bindings, there is already existing pre-built packages available :

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-ruby libqwt-ruby1.8
```

It may save you a lot of trouble and frustration.

Comment: I'm running openSUSE. The bindings available on the distribution repositories aren't built with the Qwt bindings.